# Adding String to String in an array in php

Tags: php, mysql

[image: table overview]

I am using a database to get the prices as displayed as "`Betrag`". The actual value of "`Betrag`" is "`18981`", but i am converting it by:

```
$tabledata[] = array('category' => $beschriftung, 'value' => number_format($zeile['summe'], 0, ',', '.').'&euro;', 'id' => $i);
```

My problem is that i want to get the marked text "`Anzahl: 413`" below the price, but using the `number_format`, it doesn't work. I was trying something like `$tabledata +=` or just adding it after the conversion but it didn't get my expected output. It all works with a while loop iterating over the id.

So the actual question is: 
Is it possible to add a String to an array without deleting the value which is alredy in it?
Feel free to ask questions or give comments.

Comment: it is more an issue of presentation. Show the code that builds that html structure. Also, is the text you want to add always constant or is it depending from the values of the array?

Comment: It is depending from the values of the array, it is the amount of pieces and the Betrag is the amount in €.

Comment: why don't you just add a ney key/value pair to the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats the wrong place to fix your "issue". `$tabledata` is only an array, printed somewhere else and at this point, you have to move the output of your "Betrag". That means of couse, you have to add it to your `$tabledata` array.

```
$tabledata[] = array(
    'category' => $beschriftung,
    'value' => number_format($zeile['summe'], 0, ',', '.').'&euro;',
    'id' => $i,
    'count' => $betrag
);
```

and later, you have to print it right after $value. (Something like this..)

```
foreach ($tabledata as $row) {
    // ...
    echo $row['value'];
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Anzahl:" . $row['count'];
    // ...
}
```

But thats only an example and depends on how you build your response (maybe inside an template engine, ...)

Of couse, you could also do the fast and bad way by just append the "Betrag" to the value with a `<br />` delimeter.

```
$tabledata[] = array(
    'category' => $beschriftung,
    'value' => number_format($zeile['summe'], 0, ',', '.').'&euro;' . '<br />Anzahl: ' . $betrag,
    'id' => $i
);
```

Comment: I used the "bad way" and it works since i am working with ajax and json. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to add a string to a value which already is in an array - for example

```
<?php $einArray = array('text1','text2');
$einArray[1] .= "test";
echo $einArray[1];
?>
```

Will output "text2test".

Is this the answer to your problem?